# FontExplorer X + Dropbox

Tags: fonts, dropbox

I'm looking to sync my fonts between my Macbook and iMac using a combination of FontExplorer X and Dropbox.

I've seen a few blog posts that confirm that it is possible by using a symbolic link on the database folder. But for some reason I can't seem to find that folder (I'm thinking it may have been changed/moved in the newer releases of FEX?)

It in this line [Application Support/Linotype/Font Explorer/fontexplorer x.fexdb]

But the Linotype no longer exists in Application Support.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this fixed?

I suspect if you're not seeing your Linotype App Support folder then you *may* have been looking in the wrong folder, i.e. your Mac's System Library directory, rather than the Library directory in your own user account.

For example, my directory is located at /Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Linotype/FontExplorer X.

1. In the Finder select the **Go** menu
2. Then select **> Go to folder...** (or press Shift+Command+G)
3. Enter "~/Library/Application Support/Linotype/FontExplorer X/

This should take you to the right folder.

BUT, if you're trying to sync your FontExplorer folder with Dropbox, you should read [Elliot Jay Stocks' blog post about it](http://www.elliotjaystocks.com/blog/the-cloud-centric-mac-set-up-8-months-on/) which covers the problems around trying this:

- Syncing FEX fonts and database files via Dropbox causes conflicts (i.e. FEX loses links to certain font files even though they're present)
- Elliot eventually chose to store his fonts in his local Documents folder, outside Dropbox
- Unfortunately this means syncing goes back to being a manual process - he makes semi-regular backups and then stores these on Dropbox, ready to be launched by the app on his other Mac

Comment: While the link might provide the answer it can quickly become outdated. Please can you include the main points from the link in your answer and use the link as reference. Thanks

Comment: Edited as per your request

Comment: I've been running with a setup that involves symlinking the entire Linotype folder (inside Application Support) to a folder in dropbox and has worked flawlessly for me for a year now.

I've also completely separated system/application fonts from additional fonts. With the additional fonts being handled via Font Explorer (with both machines pointing to the same font library also in dropbox).

The only constraint is that you can't have more than one linked Font Explorer's running at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that constraint? What happens if you do have more than one linked FEX running simultaneously? I've found it causes a lot of problems & if I've left FEX running on my other machine & I can't get at that machine immediately to shut down FEX, I can't do anything about it. That's why I've decided to move back to a manual sync.